# Built an ISO with remastersys but it doesn't boot?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, remastersys

I have installed remsatersys back-up from the interwebs, so i could have a custom ISO. Per the instructions on many how to i chose the option `Backup` on the menu.

However when i reboot my PC to try the ISO, GRUB shows up but regardless of what option i pick it always gives this error:

```
  Error 15: file not found
  press any key to continue...
```

I have absolutely no idea what is it? what is missing?.

**Edit:**

I was missing `initrd.lz`but now i get this error:

```
Starting up ...
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.0.1.030001-generic/modules.dep No such file
or directory
Busybox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter `help` for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
_
```

**Edit, again:**

I've given up on remastersys, what other options do i have? that don't involve manually   extracting the filesystem? or UCK?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use:

### [Customizer](http://u-customizer.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

It allows you to customize them the way you want to within the matter of few minutes (on a modern PC) running Terminal, Synaptic, Desktop session (in chroot environment) and even more so you can modify the images to fit your needs.

To Install it:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:customizer-dev-team/devel
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install customizer
```